# getting response 302 for kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed my services in kubernetes with deployments and pods. When the pod IP is given in url, I get the expected response, but when system IP is given the url is redirected with different port and getting connection refused.

Comment: add the commands that you are trying

Comment: and the service yamls

Comment: Please take a moment to visit [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get better and faster answer! Providing the necessary details, including warnings, errors, and details to reproduce your scenario will not only help you, but enable you to help others with similar issues!